# Why does Bootstrap Tooltip not work correctly when placed inside a table?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to place a [TOOLTIP](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) on table elements (`td`). Although, when the tooltip is displayed, it changes the width of the `td` element, even though the `tooltip` has a position of `absolute`.

Why is this?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8S2SR/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tooltip inserts a div after the specified dom element. In your case, the div is inserted between TDs, which messes with the render flow (block vs table display). effectively, the browser is trying to render a zero-width div with the TD border styling. Just update your code to specify a valid parent element. Most commonly the body element is used. So invoke

```
$(selector).tooltip({container:'body'});
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8S2SR/1/

If you're having a hard time viewing the hover state in your browser inspector, right click the element and it preserves the state for inspection.

Comment: I know I'm a few years late, but is there an idea to do this without adding `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip"` to every td element? It makes the code so unreadable.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to murraybiscuit's answer is adding

```
data-container="body"
```

in the attribute list. This way, you avoid using extra jquery.

Comment: You are potentially trading one parameter in a function call for an unknown number of attributes in your html.